# How do I hide html upload when flash is enable with SWFUpload?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, swfupload

How do I hide the "html upload" part when flash is enabled in the browser with SWFUpload? I looked the Wordpress source code to see how they're doing. They have a settings parameter to the SWFUpload object that looks like this:

```
custom_settings : {
    degraded_element_id : "html-upload-ui", // id of the element displayed when swfupload is unavailable
    swfupload_element_id : "flash-upload-ui" // id of the element displayed when swfupload is available
    },
```

I've put these ID numbers to the div elements. But I have not figured out what I should do more to make it work.

Please help me to just get it working, in any way.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css">#divname { display: none; } </style>
```

Display hidden makes the element hide, but it still takes up space. Display none makes the element take up no space, but it's still in the HTML code, just that it does nothing, like it's commented out.